# Converting a simple XPath query to an E4X query

Tags: javascript, xpath, e4x

One might think the corresponding E4X query for the XPath query, `//*[@foo = "bar"]`, would be `..*.(@foo == "bar")`, but that will throw an error whenever it gets to an element without a foo attribute. I am currently using `..*.(function::valueOf().@foo == "bar")` instead.

My question is if there is another, less of a hack-way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

little bit less hacky way might be using the *attribute* function:

`..*.(function::attribute("foo") == "bar")`

Comment: Thanks, that looks so much better.